# Add nested array or hash or a ruby hash to container

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm trying to get the values from a nested hash with their keys to be stored into an array but I can't go further than the first level. I have an idea of what to do but I'm stuck on how to proceed from there.

Here is my array of hash values:

```
family = [{
    dad: "Tony",
    mum: "Claire",
    relatives: [{
      uncle: "Jack",
      aunt: "Lilian",
      grandparents: ["Blake", "Amy"]
     }]
}]
```

Here is what I have tried working with:

```
array_a = []
array_b = []
array_c = []
array_d = []

def iterate_me(family)
  family.each do |member|
    if member.is_a?(Hash) || member.is_a?(Array)
      iterate_me(member)
    else
      #this below works
      array_a << member.fetch(:dad)
      array_b << member.fetch(:mum)

      #can't get this below to work
      array_c << member.fetch(:relatives: uncle or aunt) #add uncle or aunt to array
      array_d << member.fetch(:grandparents) #add blake, amy or both to array
    end
  end
end
```

also, is there a simpler way or much more ruby-like way to do this? I'm about 4 months into ruby

Comment: Show us the desired output.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom the desired output is to populate the respective arrays with the values in family hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using recursion to traverse the data structure and `fetch`, you could make use of the `map` method (assuming you know the keys in the hash beforehand).

For example, to fill `array_a` with all of the `:dad` entries you can do this

```
array_a = family.map {|x| x[:dad] }
```

or for grandparents

```
family.map {|x| x[:relatives].map { |x| x[:grandparents] }}
```

Comment: `family.map {|x| x[:relatives] }.map { |x| x[:grandparents] }` throws a `'[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)` error

Comment: looked up more about maps and nesting and this is the correct syntax. It works fine now. Fix your syntax so I accept your answer `family.map {|x| x[:relatives].map { |x| x[:grandparents] }}`